# Pivoting multiple transactions per customer

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a query which gives customer transactional info. Each customer has multiple transactions and designations these transactions go to.The query outputs CustomerId,Amount,Date,Designation. This has multiple rows for each customer.I want to pivot this so that there is only one row per customer.

[image: Original Query Output]

[image: Expected Output]

I know this is not an ideal way to represent this data, but for the purpose of this particular use case, it has to be in this format. The number of columns will be (max of the number of transactions per customer) X 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pivot over a fixed list of transactions per client, you could use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select
    CustomerId,
    max(case when rn = 1 then Amount end) Amount1,
    max(case when rn = 1 then DateReceived end) DateReceived1,
    max(case when rn = 1 then Account end) Account1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then Amount end) Amount2,
    max(case when rn = 2 then DateReceived end) DateReceived2,
    max(case when rn = 2 then Account end) Account2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then Amount end) Amount3,
    max(case when rn = 3 then DateReceived end) DateReceived3,
    max(case when rn = 3 then Account end) Account3
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by CustomerId order by DateReceived) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by CustomerId
```

This handles up to 3 transactions per client. For more, you can expand the `select` clause with more tuples of `max(case when rn = ... then ... end)` expressions.